# DataGridColumn with ItemRenderer, how to set dataProvider properly?

Tags: datagrid, flex3, itemrenderer, dataprovider

I'm building a DataGrid to display data similar to the following XML:

```
<foo>
    <entities>
        <entity>
            <name>Jim</name>
            <trend>
                <quantity>10</quantity>
                <quantity>20</quantity>
                <quantity>30</quantity>
            </trend>
       </entity>
       ...
    </entities>
</foo>
```

The idea is to have the grid display the name in one column and a small graphic (sparkline) in the second column based on the quantities.  I have a sparkline component that needs an ArrayList as a dataProvider.  My grid is set up thusly:

```
<!-- XML from dataservice transformed into XMLListCollection -->
<mx:XMLListCollection id="xmlcol" source="{xmlData.entities.entity}"/>
<mx:DataGrid id="thegrid" dataProvider="{xmlcol}">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn id="name" dataField="name" headerText="Name" />
        <mx:DataGridColumn id="spark" dataField="trend.quantity" header="Trend">
            <mx:itemRenderer>
                <mx:Component>
                     <mycomponents:Sparkline dataProvider="?????????" />
                </mx:Component>
            </mx:itemRenderer>
        </mx:DataGridColumn>
   </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

What is the best way (or anyway!) to set the dataProvider for the Sparkline component to the array of quantities?  Do I need the dataField in the enclosing DataGridColumn?  Is my approach all wrong?

As always, thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

TB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see if this solves your problem:

dataProvider="{data.trend.quantity}"